# SqoopImport component error on Talend

Tags: mysql, sqoop, talend

I am trying to run a very simple job in Talend (v.6.0.1) which basically consists of a Sqoop Import to migrate data from MySql to a Hive database running on a Cloudera distribution (CDH5.4 YARN mode). I am running Talend locally and the databases are running on a separate machine. I have created the Cloudera connection as Talend Metadata and it seems to be working properly. I have followed the steps explained [here](http://nvrit.com/BDB/?p=19) to create the job. There is an ssh tunnel connecting the Cloudera cluster (which is also running Sqoop) and the MySQL database, so in the connection path to MySQL I am using localhost.

The following error stacktrace is produced when I try to run my job:

```
    Exception in component tSqoopImport_1
java.lang.Exception: The Sqoop import job has failed. Please check the logs.
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tSqoopImport_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:512)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tLibraryLoad_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:365)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.runJobInTOS(recent_orders_migration.java:786)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.main(recent_orders_migration.java:643)
[ERROR]: org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager - Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:880)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:739)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:762)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tSqoopImport_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:508)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tLibraryLoad_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:365)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.runJobInTOS(recent_orders_migration.java:786)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.main(recent_orders_migration.java:643)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    ... 33 more
[ERROR]: org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tSqoopImport_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:508)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.tLibraryLoad_1Process(recent_orders_migration.java:365)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.runJobInTOS(recent_orders_migration.java:786)
    at dw_migration.recent_orders_migration_0_1.recent_orders_migration.main(recent_orders_migration.java:643)
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Thanks, Tamara.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you verify that you can connect to the MySQL database via JDBC from the Cloudera cluster?

Comment: Yes, I have just checked and I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try using latest mysql jar file. Probably it will work.

I have tried different way, i have create mysql connection in the metadata connection. check following Image for configuration

[image: mysql Generic JDBC Connection]

then use JDBC property as below image

[image: JDBC connection properties from metadata]

Let me know if you need any more information